# is there a way to access the property of component inside another container?

Tags: java

I am working on a project(shown below).

When I type a value in `textField` the slider will correspond the same value, meanwhile the color will change, as well as the `label(R: 0,G:0,B:0)`.

Also when you slide slider, the text of textfield, color, and label will change (I have already achieve this function). By the way, three sliders are put in a panel.
I tried to get component of panel, but there is no `getValue()` method which is weird.

Is there a way to solve this? Any help will be appreciated. (I am totally new to programming)

[image]

Comment: `Is there a way to solve this?` - Solve what? What is the question? `I tried to get component of panel, but there is no getValue() method which is weird` - What component are you trying to get? The JPanel itself? If so...why?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish what I think you are trying to do is to use [Beans Binding](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-binding.html), at least if you use NetBeans as your IDE. Bind the **JTextField** for the *Red* color to the **JSlider** for the *Red* color. Do the same for *Green* and *Blue* components. At its most basic level, beans binding is a way to connect bean properties without using event listening and handling code.

[image]

It's really not exactly clear what you are trying to accomplish here since you have not responded to the comment I provided related to your Post so I'll just leave you with a gif Image displaying a demo of what **Beans Binding** can look like in action. The demo code is too large to post here but if the provided above link is not enough to assist you then (anyone) please feel free to e-mail me for the demo source.

Comment: that's what I want to achieve, I tried to create a test class to let outside class can access the color in ColorChooser(i created a method called getCurrentColor in ColorChooser). and a label in test class to show the color.(this part i cannot solve).